# How to pass Primary Key data from server side datatable to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

Thanks in advance.

i've been using datatable a long time.. but i haven't use server side processing. well i fetched data using ssp on datatable. it wasn't that hard to so...

but i would like to know if we can post each record to another page using form at the last td of each row..

however i managed to place form on the last td of each row, but could not show primary key to the input field

below is the screenshot

[image]

```
"aProcessing": true,
 "aServerSide": true,
"ajax": "server-response.php",
"columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<form method='post' action='<?php echo $URL; ?>combatant/combdetail.html'>"+
            "<input type='text' name='ParticipantID' value='tet'>"+
            "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit'>View Detail</button></form>"
        } ]
} );
```

first column on image is ParticipantID which should be the value on the above input field.